# Building FIPS module for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, fips

I am working on an android project that requires the cryptographic libraries that are present in the application to be FIPS certified. To my knowledge there are no FIPS validated JAVA security libraries. Boucy Castle is good but its not validated. After reading some forum posts, I found out that OpenSSL's FIPS module can be used with the help of NDK.

Right now I am trying to build the fips-openssl module for Android, to do that I have created a script for the environment variables for cross compiling.

I am using [openssl-fips](http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-fips-1.2.2.tar.gz), and ndk-r8 for this project. I followed the fips [guideline](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGoQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftesthub.opensslfoundation.com%2Fosf%2Ftesting%2Fvalidation-2.0%2Fplatforms%2Fandroid%2FTestingInstructions.pdf&ei=Y5zXT7upA4eC8QThnZ3DAw&usg=AFQjCNFEzPDcoigVlgNvbk0YjYweolk-Aw&sig2=PIzKT1R0QF1S4v-z76VRzg) I found on google. I hope this gives a clear picture of what I am trying to do.

```
#! /bin/sh
export ANDROID_NDK="~/Android/android-ndk-r8"
export FIPS_SIG="${ANDROID_NDK}/incore"
export GCC_C1="/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/"
export PATH=$PATH:"${ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin";
export MACHINE=armv71
export ARCH=arm. 
export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-linux-androideabi-"
export SYSTEM=android
#export RELEASE=2.6.32.GMU 
export ANDROID_DEV="$ANDROID_NDK/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr" 
export HOSTCC=/usr/bin/gcc
```

when doing the make this is the error that i get.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [cryptlib.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abhiram/fips/openssl-fips-1.2.3/crypto'
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

When i do a "find", the cc1 executable is present in this specific directory.

```
  find . -name cc1 
./toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/libexec/gcc/mipsel-linux-android/4.4.3/cc1
./toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/cc1
./toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/libexec/gcc/i686-android-linux/4.4.3/cc1
```

Comment: "To my knowledge there are no FIPS compliant JAVA security libraries" - not true. For example, RSA Data Security's [BSAFE](http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-bsafe.htm) is FIPS validated.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the problem is in the export statement, there is a blank space where a dash should be in the PATH line. Change this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"${ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi  4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin";
```

to this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"${ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin";
```

Also, your find shows that the cc1 executable is not in the path, so add its location to the path export as well:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"${ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin":"${ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/";
```

Comment: The blankspace was a typo.I have added the path but I still get the same error. Its seems like the compiler "arm-linux-androideabigcc" is already looking in the libexec directory. 

I ran  "arm-linux-androideabigcc -print-search-dirs" and I see that the diretory is present. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I am trying to build the fips-openssl module for Android, to do that I have created a script for the environment variables for cross compiling.

OpenSSL provides a script for Android, if you are interested. You can find it on the OpenSSL wiki: [FIPS Library and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Library_and_Android).

---

> when doing the make this is the error that i get:
>
> `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1'`

It looks like your `PATH` does not include the cross-compile toolchain.

How are you invoking the script? You need to include a leading dot (".") to ensure the changes are applied to the current shell (and not the sub-shell that executes the script (which simply exits)).

Here' the first step of OpenSSL's build procedures for Android located at [FIPS Library and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Library_and_Android). Notice the leading dot:

```
$ . .setenv-android.sh
```

The results of running the script set a bunch of variables used by the OpenSSL build system:

```
$ . ./setenv-android.sh 
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT: /opt/android-ndk-r9
ANDROID_EABI: arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
ANDROID_API: android-14
ANDROID_SYSROOT: /opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN: /opt/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin
FIPS_SIG: 
CROSS_COMPILE: arm-linux-androideabi-
ANDROID_DEV: /opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr
```

---

> "${ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/"

I don't believe this is needed.

---

> export ANDROID_NDK="~/Android/android-ndk-r8"

According to the folks on the Android NDK user list, you should set both `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. The various NDK and SDK tools use those environmental variables. I suppose the SDK value would be `"~/Android/android-sdk"` for your installation.

See [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ) for details.

---

I also think you should be using `ANDROID_SYSROOT`. Its not used by the NDK or SDK tools; rather, its used by OpenSSL and passed as `sysroot` during compile.